# Change icons depending a php condition

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I assign a color value to each category of elements. I retrieve the color that has that category and I use it as background-color in a `<span>` in the following way:

```php
<span class="cat-icon" style="background-color: <?php echo esc_attr( $first_ctg->get_color() ) ?>;">
```

What I need to do is that depending on the value of that color, I must show one image source or another inside the `<span>`.

```php
if ($first_ctg->get_color() == red) 
  show img_01
elseif ($first_ctg->get_color() == blue)
  show img_02
endif;
```

How can I do this properly in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

There are more ways you could do this, I assume you have just two pictures (you can use elseifs otherwise). Solution:

```
<span class="cat-icon" style="background-color: <?php echo esc_attr( $first_ctg->get_color() ) ?>;">
<?php
$src = "img_02";

if ($first_ctg->get_color() == "red")  {
  $src = "img_01";
}
?>

<img src="<?php echo $src ?>">
```

I am finding out the image source in conditions first and then assigning its value to variable $img. Then I am echoing source to src inside php tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with PHP by checking the value of $first_ctg->get_color() and echoing the entire `<span>` element based on that value, i.e.

```
switch ( $first_ctg->get_color() ) {
    case 'red':  // or whatever value you would expect to receive from your get_color() function
        echo '<span class="cat-icon" style="background-color:#ACOLOR"><img src="PATH/TO/WHATEVER/IMAGE"><span>';
        break;
    case 'another color':
        echo '<span class="cat-icon" style="background-color:#ANOTHERCOLOR"><img src="PATH/TO/ANOTHER/IMAGE"><span>'; 
        break;
    ...
    default:
        echo '<span class="cat-icon" style="background-color:#ANOTHERCOLOR"><img src="PATH/TO/ANOTHER/IMAGE"><span>';
        break;
}
```

It's worth stating that this is arguably a case for using Javascript (or JQuery) to manipulate the DOM based on other elements or attributes, but since your question specifically asked how to do this in PHP that's the answer I gave.

Answer (score 0):

Its Very Simple you need to put some conditions like

```
if ($first_ctg->get_color() == red)
 {
    $src = "https://www.example.com/img/background.png";
 }
elseif ($first_ctg->get_color() == blue)
 {
    $src = "https://www.example.com/img/background-2.png";
 }
```

And Into img tag you need to put this variable (i.e: $src)

```
<img src="<?php echo $src;?>" title="">
```

Comment: If you want to set body background image then reply me with "yes" then i will also explain you how you can do it .

Answer (score 0):

Since a category already knows its color. Why not make the icon also a property of the category class ? Then in your vieuw you could simply write something like

```
<img src="<?php echo $first_ctg->get_icon()">
```